# Are certificates useful for intranet SSL?

Tags: security, ssl, ssh, ssl-certificate, intranet

I've been tasked with development of an intranet interface for command line software, and now I'm researching security options. Our command line application is finished, but I haven't started writing the web interface. I don't know exactly what the security requirements are for potential customers, although I believe `ssh` is generally acceptable for the command line interface. With this in mind, I'm asking for help developing a menu of choices with their associated pros/cons. Some day, we may consider releasing our web interface to the internet, so I'm willing to consider more security than currently necessary if it's easy and/or free.

I've been doing a lot of reading, and my tentative conclusion is that SSL security with no certificate is the best approach, not because less security is unacceptable, but because SSL is the standard and because it doesn't appear to be difficult to set up. I, a security non-expert, wouldn't need to explain why less security is acceptable to security non-experts. I could upgrade my application to use a certificate in the future if necessary.

Here's a list of SSL related security choices, sorted by my perception of security level with my comments. What level of protection do I need?

1. **No SSL.** This might be acceptable if our customers aren't worried about their employees seeing/changing each others' data. Their employees might want to share results with each other anyway, and I could use IP based access control and/or passwords for security.
2. **Do SSL with no certificate.** This encrypts the communication, which at least protects the data from being read by unauthorized employees. Using a password, this is the same level of security as `ssh` on the command line, right? I don't need to worry about man-in-the-middle attacks in an intranet, right? A con for this approach would be if there were loads of browser warning messages.
3. **Do SSL with a self-signed certificate.** What does this give me that no certificate gives me? If the DNS can be changed inappropriately, then the customer then my application is the least of their concerns. Worded another way, if the DNS can change, then I think `ssh` would be vulnerable too.
4. **Do SSL with a local Certificate Authority.** OpenSSL lets me make my own Certificate Authority. What does this give me that a self-signed certificate does not? I'm assuming that on a LAN, it's less important for the server to be verified.
5. **Do SSL with an external Certificate Authority.** Is there ever a reason to go this route for an intranet? I found some "intranet certificates" for sale online -- but it's not clear what they're offering I can't do myself.

For reference, this page might be useful for comparing certificates:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_faq.html#aboutcerts

[update]

[Here's](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2457649/security0/new-ssl-server-rules-go-into-effect-nov-1.html) an article discussing the risks and rules of obtaining an internal certificate from a public CA.

Comment: Maybe I could add the word "how" at the beginning of the title.

Comment: A ridiculous closure. The question is not 'too broad'. It has a one-word yes/no answer. Voting  to reopen.

Comment: 'Too broad' seems wrong but it's probably not programming, maybe ServerFault territory? Anyhow:

Comment: 2: not usually possible; there are some SSL cipher suites that don't use server certs but they are largely unimplemented in the wild. 3: as with ssh the assumption is if you want to do this securely you must pre-distribute known-good certs/keys for each server. 4: easier to manage than 3 but again the assumption would be you would roll out your internal CA to all your internal machines via an existing known-good distribution channel. 5: you would use an external CA if they can provide that service at a cheaper cost than your company employing someone suitably competent to do it internally.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, certificates are still useful for Intranet SSL.

There's an important difference between SSH and SSL-without-a-certificate: when you first connect to a server with SSH, your SSH stores the server's fingerprint. If you then try to connect to what the SSH client believes to be the same machine but gets back a different fingerprint, it alerts you that there might be someone intercepting your communications.

SSL-without-a-certificate, on the other hand, does not store the server's fingerprint. Your communications will still be encrypted, but if someone somehow hijacks the DNS server as you mentioned, or, [as Rushyo notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894868/are-certificates-useful-for-intranet-ssl/20895967#comment31387770_20895967), does ARP poisoning or something similar, they would be able to perform a man-in-the-middle attack. SSH, as previously mentioned, would (supposing you had connected to the correct server some time in the past) notice that the fingerprint had changed and alert you.

A self-signed certificate would be comparable in security to SSH. A man in the middle could generate their own self-signed certificate, but as long as your applications are configured to only accept *that* self-signed certificate, you should get an alert similar to that that SSH will give you.

A local certificate authority gives you security similar to self-signed certificates, but may be more scalable. Should you have multiple servers, each can have their own certificate, but a client only needs the top-level one to trust all of them. If a server is compromised, you can revoke its certificate rather than having to change every server's certificate.

I don't believe an external certificate authority has any advantages, other than possibly less configuration if your machines already have the certificate authority trusted.

Lastly, I don't know enough about two-factor authentication to evaluate it, but for most applications, SSL should be sufficient.

<sup>Disclaimer: I am not a security expert.</sup>

Comment: "Your communications will still be encrypted, but if someone somehow hijacks the DNS server as you mentioned, they would be able to perform a man-in-the-middle attack." There are much easier ways to accomplish this, such as ARP poisoning. SSL is not fit for purpose without a cert, period.

Comment: "less configuration if your machines already have the certificate authority trusted" is important if employees are allowed to BYOD.

Answer (score 4):

> 5. Do SSL with an external Certificate Authority. Is there ever a reason to go this route for an intranet? I found some "intranet certificates" for sale online -- but it's not clear what they're offering I can't do myself.

The benefit is that you don't need to learn how to setup your own Certificate Authority if you need to manage a decent number of certificates and/or machines. Such a certificate would already be trusted by all browsers without you needing to install your own certificates into the trusted store.

**However**, this is actually less secure because somebody could purchase a certificate for a different intranet and use it on your network. For this reason, SSL vendors no longer offer this service. For more information, see: https://www.godaddy.com/help/phasing-out-intranet-names-and-ip-addresses-in-ssls-6935

If you only have a very small intranet, then I would recommend using a self-signed certificate, and then just add each self-signed certificate to each computer's trusted store.

However, it quickly becomes impractical to install a new certificate on every computer in your intranet whenever you want to add a new computer. At this point, you want to setup your own Certificate Authority so that you only need to install a single CA certificate in each computer's trusted store.

Comment: Hey @geofflee chrome and IE keep alerting my users in the intranet with the red bar on 'https' even if I add my self signed certificate to the trusted store, I would like that green bar like normal Internet SSL configured websites, is this possible to achieve ?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Did you install the certificate into the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" certificate store? Make sure "Show physical stores" is NOT selected.

Comment: I did that :) what does this option "show physical stores mean", is it available both in chrome and IE, or it's an OS option in the certificates manager ? Can you please edit your answer to include some screenshots ? That would be great !

Comment: Also, Chrome no longer accepts SSL certificates that use SHA-1. You must either enable the EnableSha1ForLocalAnchors policy, or use SHA-2. The SHA-2 suite includes SHA-256 and SHA-512. (See: https://security.googleblog.com/2016/11/sha-1-certificates-in-chrome.html) Internet Explorer will continue to accept self-signed certificates that use SHA-1. (See: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32288.windows-enforcement-of-sha1-certificates.aspx)

Comment: The "show physical stores" optional simply allows you to select the physical location on your computer where the certificate is stored. In your case, it should be stored in the Registry. However, if you leave the option de-selected, it will automatically pick the correct physical location for you. Thus, you should NOT select this option.

Comment: @mounaim Screenshots will depend on your version of Windows, so I will not use this space to provide that for you. Instead, I recommend that you search Google. For example, here is one guide that will work for Windows Vista and Windows 7: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2008/05/08/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista/